# Definite trigonometric substitution integral - what did I do wrong?

Tags: integration

$$I = \int_0^2 \frac{dx}{4+3x^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{4} \int_0^2 \frac{dx}{3/4x^2+1}$$

$$x= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\ tan\ \theta$$

$$dx= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\ sec^2\ \theta\ d\theta$$

And here is where I may have made a mistake:

$$x = 2$$

$$arctan\ (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ (2)) = \theta$$

$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{sec^2\ \theta \ d\theta}{sec^2\ \theta}$$

$$[\frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{3}}]_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

I feel like what I did wrong was state $\theta = arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}*\frac{\pi}{3})$ which is wrong. I should just plug $\pi / 3$ for theta and solve it. However, I had that initial incorrect instinct because of habitually finding $\theta$ in terms of $x$ when solving this indefinitely. Why do I not have to solve this in terms of $x$ in this example but I do when the integral is indefinite?

Comment: @symplectomorphic $1/4 * \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Whoops yes, read too quickly

Comment: I think you meant to say $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3} ) =\frac{\pi}{3}$
which is correct as is your final answer $\frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt 3}$